# R script returns "Error in library(httr) : there is no package called ‘httr’" - what should I do?

Tags: r

I am trying to run an R code in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for sending SMS via Plivo, in my script I am using a library

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
 library(httr) 
 code ....
```

After running this I get the error below

```
Error in library(httr) : there is no package called ‘httr’
Execution halted
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4):

You need to run your `R` session and then install `httr` package into it:

```
install.packages("httr")
```

then you can use this library.

Some R packages may need some development libraries (check messages during package compilation for the hints). In this particular case we need the following:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

---

Note: on modern Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 18.10 the `httr` is packaged as [`r-cran-httr`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=r-cran-httr).

Comment: Thanks, it did work after installing the dependency like this sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Comment: So you could accept my answer :)

Comment: Of course, I accept yours, I wrote something additionally to help others if someone faces the same dependency issue.

Comment: Updated. Added info about dev-packages :)

Comment: Outstanding work.